# java code to Divides number and show the reminder and quotient

Tags: java, calculator, division

I hope this thread isnt against the rules
my problem is 
im using macos and i couldnt find a calculator that Divides number and show the reminder and quotient

so i thought there might be a java code that do that
i could program such app but im really on a hurry
couze im studing multiplicate cipher that uses gcd (greatest common diviser )
and i need to culaculate alot of number using the reminder of that calculation

so i thought i bring this here cause there is alot of experienced programs in this form

thanks in advance

Comment: There is. Use the `/` and `%` operators.

Comment: i didnt write any code cuz im in a hurry i was hoping there is a pre written code and someone can direct me to it

Comment: @AhmedNageeb that's not how this site works...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because OP is being lazy and wants us to do his homework for him/her.

Comment: @AhmedNageeb - A quick google search yields loads of tutorials, videos, code etc. I'd suggest starting there and opening a new question if you have a specific question about the code you're implementing

Comment: @brso05 i new in the form

Comment: @andyTurner im not lazy just in a hurry and i know how to program such an app i did that in my jr. year at college in c++ thanks 4 ur answer

Comment: @RobertH thanks for answering i know that but i dont have the time i was hoping that someone know site that have the code pre written

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found the code

```
//Author : Mayank Rajoria
import java.util.*;

class remainderAndQuotient {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n, q, a, k = 1, r;
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter 2 numbers");
        n = sc.nextInt();
        a = sc.nextInt();
        r = n % a;
        q = n / a;
        System.out.println("Quotient : " + q);
        System.out.println("Remainder : " + r);
    }
}
```